# How do I load a CSV into AWS RDS using an Airflow Postgres hook?

Tags: postgresql, airflow, amazon-rds

I'm trying to use the `copy_expert` hook here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook.html 
but I don't understand the syntax and I don't have an example to follow. My goal is to load a CSV into an AWS RDS instance running Postgres.

```
hook_copy_expert = airflow.hooks.postgres_hook.PostgresHook('postgres_amazon')

def import_to_postgres():
sql = f"DELETE FROM amazon.amazon_purchases; COPY amazon.amazon_purchases FROM '{path}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
        hook_copy_expert(sql, path, open=open)

t4 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'import_to_postgres',
    python_callable = import_to_postgres,
    dag = dag,
    )
```

When I run this, I get an error saying `name 'sql' is not defined`. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I got the hook to run but I got an error:

```
ERROR - must be superuser or a member of the pg_read_server_files role to COPY from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

I thought the whole point of using the Postgres hook was to use the `COPY` command in SQL without having superuser status? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run `COPY` on RDS, and you can't run psql's `\COPY` from a PostgreSQL operator.

Unless it's an enormous file, try loading the CSV data into memory with the Python csv module, and then inserting it to the DB.